# Question about anonymous class (What is the exact error)

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Robot");
    list.add("Apple");
    list.add("Box");
    
    StrComp cmp = new StrComp() {
        @Override
        public int compare (String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.length() - s2.length();
        }
    };
    
    Collections.sort(list,cmp);
}
```

There are error on "StrComp cmp = new StrComp()". Well all I did is just type the code in the text book explaining the anonymous class.. What is wrong??

Comment: There is no class or interface named `StrComp`. You meant a `Comparator` here

Comment: How shall we know what is wrong, if you don't tell us the error?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are missing something from textbook, there is no class or interface name `StrCmp` in java and you have also not defined it so it throws following error.

```
error: cannot find symbol
    StrComp cmp = new StrComp() {
    ^
  symbol:   class StrComp
```

Correct code is to use `Comparator` interface for anonymous class

```
Comparator cmp = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare (String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.length() - s2.length();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the definition of `StrCmp`. In order to get rid of the error, you need to define `StrCmp` something like

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

interface StrComp extends Comparator<String> {
    // ...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Robot");
        list.add("Apple");
        list.add("Box");

        StrComp cmp = new StrComp() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                return s1.length() - s2.length();
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(list, cmp);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Box, Robot, Apple]
```

### Using [Standard Functional Interfaces with Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6):

The standard Functional Interface, [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) makes it easier for you to do it in a succinct manner.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Robot");
        list.add("Apple");
        list.add("Box");

        Comparator<String> cmp = (s1, s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length();

        Collections.sort(list, cmp);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, the anonymous class construct creates an *anonymous* type - a type that has *no name*. It's not a 'pick a name and define it on the fly' situation.

In your code, you have a type; you use the type named `StrComp`. This construct would:

- Declare a new variable of type `StrComp` (meaning: restricted to reference either `null` or reference an instance of StrComp, or a subtype of StrComp).
- Create a new nameless subtype of StrComp, created by extending StrComp and adding the compare method you have written.
- Instantiate a new instance of this nameless type.
- Assign it to your `cmp` variable.

And none of that makes much sense if `StrComp` doesn't exist, yet. This construct is used to extend on already existing types.

As the comment already said: You probably intended to override `Comparator<String>`, thus:

```
Comparator<String> cmp = new Comparator<String>() {
   ...
}
```

***BUT NOTE***: This is obsolete java and has been obsolete for many years. Tell your teacher to learn some new java, or, get a new book.

You can now do:

```
Comparator<String> cmp = (s1, s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length();
```